# Django polymorphism in view

Tags: python, django, polymorphism

I have the following model, using Django Polymorphic:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    input = BaseInput()

class BaseInput(PolymorphicModel):
    pass

class ChildInput(BaseInput):
    name = 'child'
```

Using the python console, doing BaseInput.objects.all() resolves nicely to ChildInput automatically due to Django Polymorphic.

But in the view, the .html file, I use a for loop through Connection.objects.all() (given in the context). If I then try to access the ChildInput object like so:

```
c.input
```

(where c is the connection in the for loop)
it resolves to 'BaseInput object'.

So Polymorphic works in the python interpreter but not the view.

Any ideas?

(Python 3.4.1, Django 1.7.3, Django-polymorphic 0.6.1)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with console/view, but rather with `.objects` vs a related field. To confirm that, can you `get()` a `Connection` in the console and try `c.input` there? If that presents the same problem, can you post the full `BaseInput` model? I suspect it's an issue with default managers.

Comment: In the console this happens: 

`>>> Connection.objects.all()[0].input  
<BaseInput: BaseInput object>`

But if I do:
`>>> BaseInput.objects.all()
[<ChildInput: ChildInput object>]`

Comment: Okay, can you post your `BaseInput` model?

Comment: It is literally this:
`class BaseInput(PolymorphicModel):
    pass`

Nothing else, I just started this project.

Comment: What is the output of `BaseInput._default_manager` or `BaseInput._meta._default_manager` (forgot which one)?

Comment: `<polymorphic.manager.PolymorphicManager object at 0x0421CE10>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69079/discussion-between-knbk-and-christiaan-maks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    input = BaseInput()
```

You need to change `input` to `models.ForeignKey(BaseInput)`. This way, `input` is added as a database field on the `Connection` model, and not just as an attribute on the class.